# PDF Acrobat Verifying Signature

Tags: pdf, signature, acrobat

I am verifying a PDF with two signatures (Adobe Acrobat), both valid. One of them has a text say "cambio(s) varios" (my Adobe Acrobat is in Spanish) translating to Enghish "change(s) various", my question is I don´t know what it mean. Signatures are valid and the PDF is correct.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the PDF in question for analysis. Without the file I can merely say that there is something in your PDF causing this output but obviously I cannot tell what it is exactly.

Comment: Thanks mkl, this a link to a public folder in OneDrive:

Comment: https://1drv.ms/b/s!AnggmeMAJPFggdQP6QUBpl_2v1psTA?e=dBHvbh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to outline what this is about, the Adobe Acrobat Reader signature panel looks like this for the document at hand

[image: Signature Panel screen shot]

and the question is about the

> 1 Miscellaneous Change(s)

in-between.

## According to Adobe Documentation

In a number of documents Adobe enumerates possible modification entries and characterizes "Miscellaneous Change(s)" like this:

> Miscellaneous: Some changes which occur in memory or cannot be explicitly listed are labelled miscellaneous.

*(e.g. in "Digital Signatures Workflow Guide for the Adobe® Acrobat Family of Products")*

Now this documentation obviously is no help at all...

## According to Adobe Acrobat

Fortunately Adobe Acrobat can be asked to show "Document Integrity Properties":

[image: Document Integrity Properties]

*(Adobe Acrobat 9.5 output on "Signature Properties" - "Legal" - "View Document Integrity Properties...")*

I assume it is this detail that makes Adobe Reader warn about miscellaneous changes.

## In Your Document

Looking for a transfer function use in your document one quickly indeed finds one in a **ExtGState** resource of page 1:

[image: Page 1 dictionary]

The **TR** entry in that graphics state dictionary sets the transfer function here.

Interestingly the transfer function used is the **Identity** function! I assume that in most normal use cases setting the transfer function to **Identity** changes nothing...

## What to Do

Thus, I would propose you change your original document creation to not include transfer functions, in particular not **Identity** transfer functions. Alternatively pre-process your documents before applying the first signature and remove such functions.

Comment: mkl, exellent and very complete answer, it is exactly explanation that i was looking for. Anew thanks very much !!

Comment: Hi @CarlosDaniel .. would you mind to share how you solve this issue? bcs mine got stuck on this.. as per suggestion by mkl to remove transfer functions, could you show the way to do it? hopefully you can help on this